# Call back after all the files are uploaded in express js using busboy

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I have an Express application with multiple upload. I'm using busboy for accessing the multipart. I have to send the files to an external API server. Currently I am uploading all the files to a directory using `fs.createWriteStream()` and then after reading the files using `fs.createReadStream`, sending the files to the external API server. How can I get a callback function after uploading all the files and reading all the files? Or else can I send the files directly to the external server without saving it in the express server? Here is my code,

```
exports.create(req, res, next) => {
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    let fileCount = 0;
    let filesToSent = [];
    req.busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
        let fileNameArray = filename.split('.'),
            fileExtension = fileNameArray[fileNameArray.length - 1],
            d = new Date(),
            fileNameToSave = d.getFullYear().toString() + (d.getMonth() + 1).toString() + d.getDate().toString() + d.getTime().toString() + '_' + fileCount + '.' + fileExtension;
        fileCount += 1;
        let fileUpload = file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./app/tempupload/' + fileNameToSave));
        fileUpload.on('finish', () => {
            let uploadedFile = fs.createReadStream('./app/tempupload/' + fileNameToSave);
            uploadedFile.on('finish', () => {
                filesToSent.push(uploadedFile);
                console.log(filesToSent);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create and fire a custom event for this using EventEmitter? Or promises can also be used